# Unable to install - A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, ios13, xcode11

Ever since Xcode 11 I've not been able to run any apps on my device. They will launch in the simulator just fine. I have an iPhone 11 Max Pro.

I've tried everything I can think of to get it to work and I have no idea what to do at this point. Has anyone figured out a fix ?

I did try setting my project to Legacy build and I still have the same issue.

Here are the details of the failed install to my iPhone.

```
Details

Unable to install "App Test"
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620395
--
App installation failed
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620395
Failure Reason: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001251586e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000125158de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000012519856a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 164
    3   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010b27cc22 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000125198301 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1589
    5   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000125020a25 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4523
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010b3ade8a __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    7   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010b3af562 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d6ca583 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d6cb50e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d6d0ace _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d6d1452 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 363
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff6d6daa9e _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6d9256fc _pthread_wqthread + 290
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff6d924827 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue today and I could not fix it either with the proposed solutions that are out there, because they pointed into the wrong direction.

Do you, by any chance, have frameworks included in your project and set them to "embed without signing"? Changing the included frameworks to "embed & sign" fixed this issue for me.

Not properly re-signing external frameworks seems to cause problems when attempting to install the binary to a real device. The executable mentioned in "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." does in this context refer to the insufficiently signed external framework.